# Validation of a formset nested in a Django form

Tags: python, django, validation, inline-formset

I am trying to implement a form in two parts using a `SessionWizardView` using Django 1.5:

- 1st part: ProjectFormStep1 which is a `ModelForm` (the model is `Project`)
- 2nd part: ProjectFormStep2 (same form and model)

In ProjectFormStep2, one of the fields, `contreparties`, is associated to a formset:

```
contreparties = inlineformset_factory(Project, Contreparties_Cagnotte, form=Contreparties_CagnotteForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

(I figured I could declare a field like this thanks to the fix https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18830 )

The relevant forms, defined in forms.py, are:

```
class Contreparties_CagnotteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Contreparties_CagnotteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['project'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['lower_bound'].error_messages = {'invalid':'Saississez un montant valide (ex:52.50)','max_decimal_places': "Merci de saisir %s chiffres après la virgule",'required': 'Merci de saisir un montant minimal pour cette contrepartie'}
        self.fields['lower_bound'].required = True
        self.fields['text'].required = True
    class Meta:
        model = Contreparties_Cagnotte
        exclude = ()
        required_fields = ['text','lower_bound','text']
        widgets = {
        'project': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'span12 textcagnotte','rows':4,'resize':'vertical','required':''}),
        'lower_bound': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'span12','required':''})
        }
```

models.py:

```
class Contreparties_Cagnotte(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project',blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=3000,blank=True,null=True)
    lower_bound = models.DecimalField('lower_montant', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I know I can validate the formset separately from its parent form, but if I do so, the user is not redirected to the right page in the Wizard. Ideally I would like the validation of the formset to take place during the validation of the form so the user is directed to the page associated with the formset's parent form if the formset is not validated.

How do I override the `is_valid()`method of ProjectFormStep2 so that it returns `False`if the formset associated with the field `contreparties` is not valid?

UPDATE: Here is what I do during the "done" method of the `SessionWizardView` (views.py):

```
if form.is_valid():

    # # # # # #
    # Right now I am validating the formset separately from its parent form. 

        if '1-crowdfunding_enabled' in self.request.POST.dict().keys() and self.request.POST.dict()['1-crowdfunding_enabled'] == 'on':
            project = form.save(commit = False)
            id = project.id
            formation_formset = inlineformset_factory(Project, Contreparties_Cagnotte, form=Contreparties_CagnotteForm, formset=RequiredFormSet, can_delete=True, extra=1)
            formcagnotte = formation_formset(self.request.POST,instance=project)

            # I want to do this bit during "form.is_valid() !"
            if formcagnotte.is_valid():
                project = form.save(commit = True)
                project.save()
                formcagnotte.save()
            else:
                return redirect('memberprojectadd')
    #
    #
    # # # # # #
```

Comment: You may want to show us your view code as well as urls about how to create wizardview.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Apart from the "done" method, I haven't overridden any of the methods described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/ (get_context_data etc...)

Comment: What I would think is validation of formset should happen similar to other forms when user submits data for some step. Validation shouldn't happen in `done()` method.

Comment: Yes, the validation I did in  the `done()` method is unrelated to the validation done in each step. It is the validation of the second step that I'm interested in - but I don't think anything in my view code would be any help in that case.